Visual Studio 2019 cursor jumps half page when creating struct
Using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 7.
Haven't used VS2019 for a few months and today it prompted me to install an update. Surprise surprise, something broke.
When I create a struct and hit new line for the brackets, the cursor jumps VERY far:

Unfortunately I don't know what version I had previously. However, afterwards I installed an earlier version (16.11.27) which works on my other computer but I still get the same problem.
Does anyone know what causes this/how to fix it?

Try to switch Theme from one to other, and check your GPU card if it requires updates
